# How can I access the nuget package manager console on ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04

So I installed ubuntu 18.04.2 on this little laptop that I just bought, the thinkpad x220. I'm trying to make it into a machine with which I can program asp.net core applications on. However I can't for the life of me find how to write commands in the Package Manager Console in the Ubuntu terminal.

For example if you open visual studio on windows and go Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console. This opens the Package Manager Console. I want to be able to access this on Ubuntu. How can I access this via the terminal?

I am currently using VSCode/Vim as my text editor. I have installed both dotnet, powershell and just now nuget. I have read through `dotnet -h` and `nuget -h` but wasn't able to find anything to solve this problem. I found some other useful bits of information though, so that was good.

The reason I am trying to find the Package Manager Console is because I am working my way through an Udemy course on asp.net core and I need to enter the update-database command.

Comment: Does `dotnet ef database update` do it for you? I don’t think the Powershell commands are available on other platforms than Windows.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to work. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Appreciate it mate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Nuget Package Manager Console in Visual Studio is just a Powershell shell and allows running the commandlets provided by .NET. It isn’t available on other platforms, but for Entity Framework database handling you can use the `dotnet ef database` commands, in this case `dotnet ef database update`.

More information of these command line tools in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet).